# Proof verification: $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\not\in \mathbb{N}$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, solution-verification

Suppose not. $\implies \exists m\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $m\geq2$ and $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{m}=S\in\mathbb{N}$.

Pick $k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $2^k\leq m$ but $2^{k+1}>m$: so $2^k$ is the greatest power less than or equal to $m$.

And if $m=2^lm'$ with $m'$ odd, we have $k\geq l$

$\implies 2^kS=\frac{2^k}{1}+\frac{2^k}{2}+\cdots+\frac{2^k}{m}$

$\implies 2^kS = \frac{2^k}{1}+\frac{2^{k-1}}{1}+\frac{2^k}{3}+\cdots+1+\cdots+\frac{2^{k-l}}{m'}$ (if $m=2^k$, then $\frac{2^k}{m}$ is the $1$, and no $1$ in the middle)

Let $L=$ lcm of the denominators of RHS: $L$ is an odd number.

$\implies 2^kSL=2^kL+2^{k-1}L+2^k\frac{L}{3}+\cdots+L+\cdots+2^{k-l}\frac{L}{m'}$ (note that each fraction of the form $\frac{L}{x}$ is an integer)

$\implies 2^kSL=2\left(2^{k-1}L+2^{k-2}L+2^{k-1}\frac{L}{3}+\cdots+2^{k-l-1}\frac{L}{m'}\right)+L$

(if $l=k$, then $2^{k-l-1}\frac{L}{m'}$ is not inside the parenthesis since $m=2^lm'=2^km'=2^k\implies 2^{k-l}\frac{L}{m'}=L$)

We could factor $2$ out from the RHS since before multiplying $2^k$, originally each denominator contained at most $k-1$ power of $2$ except $2^k$ itself. And the $L$ term on the RHS was that $1/2^k$.

Since $k\geq1$, LHS is an even number while RHS is an odd number. Which is a contradiction.

From above, did I miss anything or is there something unclear/wrong?

Comment: I think it looks good.

Comment: With $S(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n 1/j:$ By induction on $n\ge 2$ we have $\forall n\ge 2\,(P(n)\,) $ where $P(n)$ is: $[\,S(n)=a_n/(2^{m_n}\cdot b_n)$ where $a_n, b_n , m_n\in \Bbb N$ with $a_n,b_n$ odd and $2^{m_n}\le n<2^{1+m_n}\,].$...The inductive step $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ splits into 2 cases: when $n$ is a power of $2$, and when $n$ is not.. I am sorry that I am too tired to check your work... My edit was for a typo \new for \ne in the title.

Comment: Saw this on a blackpenredpen youtube video very recently :)